# When and why do I have to use "trait" for multinomial multilevel models with MCMCglmm in R?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, markov-chain-montecarlo, mixed-model, glmm

I want to estimate a multilevel multinomial logit model but I am struggling with the terminology and notation used by the R-package `MCMCglmm`. There is documentation available in form of a [J Stat Softw article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i02) and [course notes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf).
According to the article, "the [MCMCglmm] syntax used to specify the model closely follows that used by asreml" (Hadfield 2010: 6). Consequently, some abbreviations like `us`="unstructured" and `idh`="independent heterogeneous" are never stated explicitly in the MCMCglmm documentation, although they are well presented in formulas. Unfortunately, I am only acquainted with the notation for hierarchical models in the social sciences and I have no experience with ASReml.

The examples of multinomial multilevel models in the MCMCglmm course notes are subsumed under multiresponse models and the course notes (p. 91) show that `trait` is used as identifier when the dataset is reshaped for estimating multiresponse models.

1. Is it necessary to use `trait` in the fixed (or random) formula also for models with a nominal outcome variable like employment status or gender (in contrast to a real multiresponse variable)?
2. Does the inclusion of `trait` change the estimated formula or is it only a signifier for MCMCglmm to expect reshaped data?
3. Can I define the error structure without using `trait`, e.g. by specifying the error structure for coefficients from the fixed part?

Here is an (almost working) example code using a typical social science survey dataset:

```
library(nnet)
library(MCMCglmm)

# Load dataset from TraMineR-package
data(mvad, package="TraMineR")

### Create variable "region" for 2nd level
attach(mvad)
mvad$region[Belfast=="yes"] <- "Belfast"
    mvad$region[N.Eastern=="yes"] <- "N.Eastern"
mvad$region[Southern=="yes"] <- "Southern"
    mvad$region[S.Eastern=="yes"] <- "S.Eastern"
mvad$region[Western=="yes"] <- "Western"
detach(mvad)

# Add identifier for complete cases 
mvad$complete <- complete.cases(mvad[, c("Jul.93", "male", "Grammar", 
                                         "gcse5eq", "funemp", "region")])

# Multinomial logit model without random effects using nnet-package
multinom(Jul.93 ~ male + Grammar + gcse5eq + funemp + region, 
         data = mvad[mvad$complete==TRUE, ])

# Multinomial logit models with random effects using MCMCglmm
mod1 <- MCMCglmm(Jul.93 ~ trait + male + Grammar + gcse5eq + funemp,
                random = ~ region, rcov = ~ us(trait):units,
                family = "categorical", verbose=FALSE,
                data=mvad[mvad$complete==TRUE, ])
# Including trait and defining rcov gives an estimable command

mod2 <- MCMCglmm(Jul.93 ~ male + Grammar + gcse5eq + funemp,
                 random = ~ region, rcov = ~ us(trait):units,
                 family = "categorical", verbose=FALSE,
                 data=mvad[mvad$complete==TRUE, ])
# Command works as well, but is trait now only used for the error terms?

mod3 <- MCMCglmm(Jul.93 ~ male + Grammar + gcse5eq + funemp,
                 random = ~ region,
                 family = "categorical", verbose=FALSE,
                 data=mvad[mvad$complete==TRUE, ])
# Command does not work as definition of error structure using e.g. "us(trait):units" is needed.
```

**Reference:**
Hadfield, J.D. (2010) 'MCMC Methods for Multi-Response Generalized Linear Mixed Models: The MCMCglmm R Package', Journal of Statistical Software 33(2): 1–22.